# Rails, create an object when another instance is accessed or created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a Rails newbie and I'm to handle a situation for the first time.

I have an ActiveRecord class, Video.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  def generate_html_for_content
    raw_embed
  end

  private

  def save_image
    self.remote_screenshot_url = extract_thumb if screenshot.blank?
  end

  def save_raw_embed
    self.raw_embed = create_embed
  end

  def extract_thumb
    if is_youtube_video?
      youtube_image
    else
      'http://placehold.it/160x90'
    end
  end

  def create_embed
    youtube_embed if is_youtube_video?
  end

  def is_youtube_video?
    # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmc21V-zBq0
    url.include? 'youtu'
  end

  def youtube_id
    url.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/)[1]
  end

  def youtube_embed
    "<div class=\"embeddedContent\"><iframe id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"1080\" height=\"607.5\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}?autohide=1?rel=0&color=white\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>"
  end

  def youtube_image
    "http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{youtube_id}/0.jpg"
  end
end
```

I have also two callback

```
before_save :save_image
before_save :save_raw_embed
```

When I create a new video from my form the model add to the video table the video thumbnail and the video embed code I will use later in my views.

I don't like this spaghetti code, and I want to use a gem called "video_info" that give me methods to get embed code, thumbnail and everything.

I add a method:

```
def create_video_object
  video_object = VideoInfo.new(url)
end
```

`video_object` has all the methods I need so I can delete the ugly methods above.
My question is: how can I create a video_object every time an instance of `Video.rb` is accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create such an object every time a video is created, because the `VideoInfo` will not be persisted into the database.

The easiest way is to just add an `info` method to your `Video` model that initializes and returns an instance of `VideoInfo`:

```
def info
  VideoInfo.new(url)
end
```

Then use that method like this:

```
@video = Video.new(url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLzxrzFCyOs')
@video.info.provider
#=> 'YouTube'
```